# Enabling C code to run as C++ code

Tags: c++, c, file-io, duplicates

I have a C program that finds duplicate files within a directory. The program is executed on the command line and passed 2 arguments. One is the parent directory, and argument two is the file name. It is working code in c, but I have a GUI and other files for "microservices" written in c++.

How would one call this C code from a c++ file?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

//Compile:          gcc dreamduplicatefinder.c -o dreamduplicatefinder.exe
//Run:              ./dreamduplicateFinder.exe parent_dir filename...

#define false 0
#define true  1

int duplicateCount = 0;

int FindDuplicates(char* path, char* fileName);
int CompareFiles(char* originalFile, char* currFile);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Two additional arguments are expected: Parent dir, file to find duplicates of...

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s 'Base Directory' 'File Name'\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    //argv[1] = base dir, argv[2] = file to find duplicates of; e.g argv[1] = /home,
    //argv[2] = "file.txt"...

    FindDuplicates(argv[1], argv[2]);
    printf("\n\nFound %d duplicate(s)\n", duplicateCount);
    return 0;
}


int FindDuplicates(char* path, char* fileName)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dp;
    struct dirent *result;
    struct stat statp;

    char absoluteFilePath[255];

    if ((dir = opendir(path)) == NULL)
    {
        //printf(dir);                  //error could becuase trying to open shortcut or corrupt folder.
        printf("%s\n",path);
        perror("Failed to open directory");

        return -1;
    }


    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        //readdir returns . and .. which we should ignore...
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
        {
            //find file full path, relative to base path. e.g, a /home/file.txt...

            //copy path to absoluteFilePath...
            strcpy(absoluteFilePath, path);

            //append / at end...
            strcat(absoluteFilePath, "/");

            //append filename to path...
            strcat(absoluteFilePath, dp->d_name);


            //check if the current file is actually file or dir...
            stat(absoluteFilePath, &statp);

            if (S_ISDIR(statp.st_mode))     //is a directory...
            {
                //recurse through this dir...
                FindDuplicates(absoluteFilePath, fileName);
            }
            else if (S_ISREG(statp.st_mode))    //is a file...
            {
                //check for duplicates here...
                //compare current file with the file specified by user...

                if (strcmp(fileName, absoluteFilePath))
                {
                    if (CompareFiles(fileName, absoluteFilePath))
                    {
                        //yes, duplicate; print it...
                        printf("%s\n", absoluteFilePath);
                        duplicateCount++;
                    }
                }

            }       //end else if (S_ISREG(statp.st_mode))...

        }       //if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dp->d_name,".."))...
    }       //end while...

    closedir(dir);
    return 0;

}


int CompareFiles(char* originalFile, char* currFile)
{
    //two step comparison: (1) first check size; if not same, return false.
    //If equal, (2) compare file content.If equal, return true, false otherwise...

    struct stat statOriginal, statCurr;
    stat(originalFile, &statOriginal);
    stat(currFile, &statCurr);

    //Step 1...
    if ((int)statOriginal.st_size != (int)statCurr.st_size)  //size not same...
        return false;

    //Step 2...
    //size matches, files can be same; confirm it by matching both file contents...

    int fdOriginal = open(originalFile, O_RDONLY);
    int fdCurr = open(currFile, O_RDONLY);

    if (fdOriginal == -1 || fdCurr == -1)
        return false;       //error occurred, not sure if file is duplicate...


                            //we will read file in small chunks and compare...

    int chunkSize = 1024, bytesRead;
    char *bufferOriginal = (char*)malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(char));
    char *bufferCurr = (char*)malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(char));


    while (true)
    {
        //read file in chunk...
        bytesRead = read(fdOriginal, bufferOriginal, chunkSize);
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
            break;      //end of file...

        bytesRead = read(fdCurr, bufferCurr, bytesRead);

        //compare buffer...
        if (strcmp(bufferOriginal, bufferCurr))     //if content not matching...
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My errors include: (from compareFiles function)

2x  'open' identifier not found

2x  'read' identifier not found

The working code for those curious.
Thank you @MarcusMüller & @JesperJuhl

```
#include "stdafx.h"             //there is nothing in this header

#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    //Compile:          gcc <name of this file>.cpp -o <nameOfThisFile>.exe
    //Run:              <nameOfThisFile> parent_dir filename...

#define false 0
#define true  1

    int duplicateCount = 0;

    int FindDuplicates(char* path, char* fileName);
    int CompareFiles(char* originalFile, char* currFile);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        //Two additional arguments are expected: Parent dir, file to find duplicates of...

        if (argc != 3)
        {
            printf("Usage: %s 'Base Directory' 'File Name'\n", argv[0]);
            return -1;
        }

        //argv[1] = base dir, argv[2] = file to find duplicates of; e.g argv[1] = /home,
        //argv[2] = "file.txt"...

        FindDuplicates(argv[1], argv[2]);
        printf("\n\nFound %d duplicate(s)\n", duplicateCount);
        return 0;
    }


    int FindDuplicates(char* path, char* fileName)
    {
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *dp;
        struct dirent *result;
        struct stat statp;

        char absoluteFilePath[255];

        if ((dir = opendir(path)) == NULL)
        {
            //possibly trying to open shortcut or corrupt folder typically.
            printf("Failed to open directory %s \n",path);
            return -1;
        }


        while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            //readdir returns . and .. which we should ignore...
            if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
            {
                //find file full path, relative to base path. e.g, a /home/file.txt...

                //copy path to absoluteFilePath...
                strcpy(absoluteFilePath, path);

                //append / at end...
                strcat(absoluteFilePath, "/");

                //append filename to path...
                strcat(absoluteFilePath, dp->d_name);


                //check if the current file is actually file or dir...
                stat(absoluteFilePath, &statp);

                if (S_ISDIR(statp.st_mode))     //is a directory...
                {
                    //recurse through this dir...
                    FindDuplicates(absoluteFilePath, fileName);
                }
                else if (S_ISREG(statp.st_mode))    //is a file...
                {
                    //check for duplicates here...
                    //compare current file with the file specified by user...

                    if (strcmp(fileName, absoluteFilePath))
                    {
                        if (CompareFiles(fileName, absoluteFilePath))
                        {
                            //yes, duplicate; print it...
                            printf("This is a duplicate! %s\n", absoluteFilePath);
                            duplicateCount++;
                        }
                    }

                }       //end else if (S_ISREG(statp.st_mode))...

            }       //if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dp->d_name,".."))...
        }       //end while...

        closedir(dir);
        return 0;

    }


    int CompareFiles(char* originalFile, char* currFile)
    {
        //two step comparison: (1) first check size; if not same, return false.
        //If equal, (2) compare file content.If equal, return true, false otherwise...

        struct stat statOriginal, statCurr;
        stat(originalFile, &statOriginal);
        stat(currFile, &statCurr);

        //Step 1...
        if ((int)statOriginal.st_size != (int)statCurr.st_size)  //size not same...
            return false;

        FILE* fdOriginal;
        if (fdOriginal = fopen(originalFile, "r")) {
            if (fdOriginal == NULL) { fputs("File error", stderr); return false; }
        }
        else return false;        //error occurred, not sure if duplicate
        FILE* fdCurr;
        if (fdCurr = fopen(currFile, "r")) {
            if (fdCurr == NULL) { fputs("File error", stderr); return false; }
        }
        else return false;

        int chunkSize = 1024, objsRead;
        char *bufferOriginal = (char*)malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(char));
        if (bufferOriginal == NULL) { fputs("Memory error for buff orig", stderr); exit(2); }

        char *bufferCurr = (char*)malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(char));
        if (bufferCurr == NULL) { fputs("Memory error for buff curr", stderr); exit(2); }


        while (true)
        {
            //read file in chunk...
            //std::size_t fread( void* buffer, std::size_t size, std::size_t count, std::FILE* stream );
            objsRead = fread(bufferOriginal, sizeof(char), chunkSize , fdOriginal);
            if (objsRead <= 0)
                break;      //end of file...

            objsRead = fread(bufferCurr, sizeof(char), objsRead, fdCurr);

            //compare buffer...
            if (strcmp(bufferOriginal, bufferCurr))     //if content not matching...
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why are doing this? Have you tried to talk to a frenchman  in English?

Comment: You can call C code from C++, why do you want to change it?

Comment: I want a translator function so I don't have to learn French.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work that way. English has a lot of phrases that don't exist in French, and French has a lot of phrases that don't exist in English. C and C++ are just the same. You can't just "translate" one to the other. There are C ways of doing things that feel unnatural and have downsides in C++ – all your string manipulation belongs in that category. So "translating my C to (proper) C++" is actually "reimplementing the program in C++". Just like you can't translate an English novel to French word by word and hope it'll read just as good as the original, or even just mean the same.

Comment: I could not say it better myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually just wouldn't do that. You'd wrap it in a C function, and compile it to an object file.

Then you'd include your C header with `extern "C" {…}`, and just call that function from C++.

When building your executable, you'd link in the object file containing your C function. Done!

Note: C isn't C++, and albeit your code not being illegal in C++ (as far as I can instantly tell), it does very "ugly" things (like `#define`ing `true` and `false` – ugh, that would already be a bad idea in C, to be honest). So, deal with it like you would deal with code in Fortran, or Java, or any other language that has a calling convention that you can use from C++ (which, usually, *is* the C calling convention): Just use it as an extern object.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation of a topic that I'm sure seems obvious to you. I understood your metaphors to French vs English language.

Answer (score 1):

Using `::open` and `::read` should cause the functions to be found.

You may also want to replace the C headers (like "string.h") with their C++ equivalent versions (like "cstring").

Your defines for `true` and `false` should also go. In C++ those are proper bools, not integers. This means the return type of `CompareFiles` should be changed to `bool`.

And you should wrap `duplicateCount` in an anonymous namespace - or return it from the function that updates it (either by returning a small struct with two ints, or by using a `std::pair` or `std::tuple`) - global variables are evil.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Those are great places to start. Do you think in my case this strategy would be easiest to go line by line and modify my code to be designed for c++ compilation?

Comment: no, that would be a suboptimal approach – when you're already rewriting your code, you'd use the C++ standard libraries, and then you'd drop most of your program's logical structure. It would basically be a reimplementation. So, I honestly believe that to just fix your *compiler errors*, this is the easiest way. To produce bug-free C++-callable functionality: see my answer. (Jesper, hope you don't mind my interpretation of the situation)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree with you.